# Ode solver for a system of odes in "compact" form

Tags: python, numpy, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a set of odes in the compact or matrix form in python. The ode is in the following form:

```
dydt = (np.dot((A-D),y) - np.dot(np.dot(np.diag(y),A),y))
```

In which `A` and `D` are N by N matrices and `y` is N by 1, therefore `dydt` is also N by 1. The problem is what the ode function returns is a list of lists, which has a dimension of (N,1) but what odeint solver accepts is only a list with dimension (N,). So it gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.

I have gone through a lot of examples and questions asked by other users but could not find my answer.

Comment: Try to shorten to `dydt = (A-D).dot(y) - y*A.dot(y)`, it should give you the same function and avoids the upcasting caused by the diagonal matrix. Otherwise, use the `.flatten()` method.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you suggested but the dimension is still (N,1). The .flatten() operator does not also help because the dydt is already flat but with (N,1), not (N,) (which is apparently the only valid dimension for odeint)

Comment: Then try with `.reshape(-1)`, that should reduce the array dimensions to one. What is the type and size of `A` and `D`?

Comment: A and D were lists, I converted them to array and then used .reshape(-1) and it worked! Thank you!